# Failed to run LoopBack Application with API Connect on IBM

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, ibm-datapower, apiconnect

I've create a LoopBack project on API Designer (IBM Toolkit to manage APIs and applications), set the Datasource, attach it to the models and the save was successful. Once I tried to run the application locally by selecting `DataPower Gateway Policies` and clicking on Run button, it occured an error with:

```
Service inventory started but did not initialize within the timeout period. Dumping log buffer.

2018-04-06T14:43:52.994Z pid:12620 worker:1 Cannot find module 'node-report/api': skipping optional dependency
2018-04-06T14:43:53.697Z pid:12620 worker:1 Web server listening at: http://localhost:4001
2018-04-06T14:44:00.590Z pid:12620 worker:1 Connection failed : Error: Handshake inactivity timeout
2018-04-06T14:44:00.591Z pid:12620 worker:1 A new test will be done for the next request.
2018-04-06T14:44:02.615Z pid:12620 worker:1 events.js:183
2018-04-06T14:44:02.615Z pid:12620 worker:1       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2018-04-06T14:44:02.615Z pid:12620 worker:1       ^
2018-04-06T14:44:02.615Z pid:12620 worker:1 Error: Handshake inactivity timeout
2018-04-06T14:44:02.615Z pid:12620 worker:1     at Handshake.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\apis\inventory\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:164:17)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.615Z pid:12620 worker:1     at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.615Z pid:12620 worker:1     at Handshake.emit (events.js:208:7)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.616Z pid:12620 worker:1     at Handshake._onTimeout (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\apis\inventory\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:129:8)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.616Z pid:12620 worker:1     at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.616Z pid:12620 worker:1     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.616Z pid:12620 worker:1     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.616Z pid:12620 worker:1     --------------------
2018-04-06T14:44:02.616Z pid:12620 worker:1     at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\apis\inventory\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:145:48)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.616Z pid:12620 worker:1     at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\apis\inventory\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:23)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.616Z pid:12620 worker:1     at PoolConnection.connect (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\apis\inventory\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:130:18)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.616Z pid:12620 worker:1     at Pool.getConnection (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\apis\inventory\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:48:16)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.616Z pid:12620 worker:1     at MySQL.connect (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\apis\inventory\node_modules\loopback-connector-mysql\lib\mysql.js:90:17)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.616Z pid:12620 worker:1     at Object.initializeDataSource [as initialize] (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\apis\inventory\node_modules\loopback-connector-mysql\lib\mysql.js:44:28)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.616Z pid:12620 worker:1     at DataSource.setup (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\apis\inventory\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\datasource.js:470:19)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.616Z pid:12620 worker:1     at new DataSource (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\apis\inventory\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\datasource.js:138:8)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.616Z pid:12620 worker:1     at Registry.createDataSource (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\apis\inventory\node_modules\loopback\lib\registry.js:362:12)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.616Z pid:12620 worker:1     at dataSourcesFromConfig (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\apis\inventory\node_modules\loopback\lib\application.js:522:19)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.616Z pid:12620 worker:1     at Function.app.dataSource (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\apis\inventory\node_modules\loopback\lib\application.js:229:14)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.616Z pid:12620 worker:1     at C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\apis\inventory\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\executor.js:191:9
2018-04-06T14:44:02.616Z pid:12620 worker:1     at C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\apis\inventory\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\executor.js:282:5
2018-04-06T14:44:02.616Z pid:12620 worker:1     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.617Z pid:12620 worker:1     at forEachKeyedObject (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\apis\inventory\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\executor.js:281:20)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.617Z pid:12620 worker:1     at setupDataSources (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\apis\inventory\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\executor.js:181:3)
2018-04-06T14:44:02.795Z pid:10000 worker:0 ERROR supervisor worker id 1 (pid 12620) accidental exit with 1
(node:10000) [DEP0007] DeprecationWarning: worker.suicide is deprecated. Please use worker.exitedAfterDisconnect.
```

Besides, I've already checked pre-requisties of API Connect with:

node.js: `v8.10.0`
  npm: `v5.8.0`
  apiconnect: `v5.0.8.2`

Docker:

```
Client:
 Version:       18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    0520e24
 Built: Wed Mar 21 23:06:28 2018
 OS/Arch:       windows/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.03.0-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.4
  Git commit:   0520e24
  Built:        Wed Mar 21 23:14:32 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

Docker-compose:

```
docker-compose version 1.20.1, build 5d8c71b2
docker-py version: 3.1.4
CPython version: 3.6.4
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
```

In addition, I've set Docker settings with 4096MB of RAM, 2CPUs and shared with C:\ Drive.

I've search and read similar issue but didn't figured out where is the exact problem. Any Help please!

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the application couldn't get a connection to your MySQL database.

If your DB is running on your local machine, then your connection string needs to be altered to hit the Docker gateway (usually 172.17.0.1) instead of localhost itself (which would be a pointer to the running docker container).

If MySQL is running elsewhere, then either it's down or you have a networking issue.

Once you resolve the MySQL connectivity, your application should start along with the other components.

Comment: I checked DataSource test connection and it was successful and for connection string I used ClearDB as a host. (**********cleardb.net). It's running and also I checked the network. It's working normally. Nothing of that has solved my problem..